# Row size limitation in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

So I know that Teradata has a limitation of 64k bytes per row. I have a wide table that I need to export to Teradata and there are some fields (varchar (5000)) that go along with that. We have seen cases where the row size exceeds this limitation.

So, my question is, how can we overcome this situation? We cannot trim the large VARCHARS in our source as they are necessary to the downstream business users. Splitting up the table is always the option, but are there any other ways in Teradata that this can be handled?

Comment: You may need a second table that uses the same key. :/ Is there anything else being stored on the record that could be normalized to another table as an alternative?

Comment: Nothing really. Its a pretty flat table that uses only 1 column as its primary key.

Comment: Teradata 16.00 increases row size to 1MB. Otherwise, as JNevill mentions split the table into two with the same primary index. This allows them to be joined together AMP-local on a row-key merge join, one of the most efficient joins in Teradata.

Comment: Thank you Rob. If you want to post that comment as an answer, I can accept it and give you credit for that! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata 16.00 increases row size to 1MB. Otherwise, as JNevill mentions split the table into two with the same primary index. This allows them to be joined together AMP-local on a row-key merge join, one of the most efficient joins in Teradata.