# Terdata Column size error exceeding 64k byte limit

Tags: size, teradata, informatica-powercenter, teradata-sql-assistant

We have a requirement to increase the existing  3 columns  from VARCHAR(4096) to VARCHAR(11000), We pull the data from oracle table using informatica
and load it to teradata table.
As per my testing, Informatica job was successful  till i made all 3 columns as VARCHAR(10001) in informatica and teradata. ( This table has other columns also).
But after 10001, if i increase the size,I was getting error

`ERROR] Type:(Teradata DBS Error), Error: (The available data bytes in the table's perm row has exceeded the 64k byte limit.)`

I tried giving CLOB datatype in target table for one column,even that was failing.

Found one of the posts in stackoverflow which talks about splitting the table because of the size limitation in teradata16

[Row size limitation in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228089/row-size-limitation-in-teradata)

Could you please let me know if there is any option to do it without splitting the table ?

Comment: Assuming those columns are UNICODE (3*11000*2 > 64k): is it possible to switch at least one of them to LATIN? Or check when you're going to upgrade to TD16+

Comment: Can you use Informatica data types STRING or TEXT. They should be able to handle 104,857,600 characters. So convert the column data type to TEXT while reading from Oracle and propagate it throughout till the target. make sure data type changed everywhere. Also this can slow mapping down so pls be mindful of that too.

Comment: @dnoeth :Teradata version we have is 16.20.32.13c, I treid changing one column to VARCHAR(11000) LATIN, and other two as VARCHAR(10000) UNICODE,its failing with A column or character expression is larger than the max size error

Comment: @KoushikRoy : Tried with both Text and String in informatica, its giving me the same 64k byte limit error

Comment: What's the exact errror message? TD16+ increased the maximum row size to 1 MB, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1Ms8rWHdBhcwr0PzwAWcDw/Hw0x7Cfl2PAAHfjwn2RidQ Maybe your system was upgraded from an earlier version and it was not enabled. Approach your DBA then.

Comment: sorry to ask a doubt, when exactly its erring out - Reading from Oracle or writing into Teradata table? If second case, have you tried writing into a flat file. If flat file dump works then i think issue is with Teradata DB/ODBC Driver that writes into. You already checked data types Latin/Unicode, but have you checked if DataDirect driver has any limitations or not?